# Why does verification of a detached signature result in a "Message digest did not match" error for OpenPGP.js?

Tags: javascript, openpgp, openpgp.js

I can sign and verify a test file through `gpg` without issue, but verifying the signature through OpenGPG.js fails with the error, "Message digest did not match." Why is this?

```
$ gpg --armor --quiet --batch --yes --detach-sig index.html
$ gpg --verify index.html.asc index.html
gpg: Signature made Wed 25 Nov 2020 08:26:34 PM PST
gpg:                using RSA key C361FDC3F93B9E8F8BD7E08D5F873051B2D6C347
gpg: Good signature from <key>
$ node sandbox.js 
{ signatures:
   [ { keyid: [Keyid],
       verified: [Promise],
       signature: [Signature],
       valid: false,
       error:
        Error: Message digest did not match
            at Signature.verify (/home/caleb/src/islands/node_modules/openpgp/dist/openpgp.js:41176:11)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
            at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
            at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
            at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3) } ],
  data: 'Test!\n' }
```

sandbox.js (based on [the OpenPGP.js example](https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/index.html#create-and-verify-detached-signatures)):

```js
openpgp = require('openpgp');
fs = require('fs');

async function sandbox() {
    path = './'

    let msg_data = fs.readFileSync(path + "index.html", 'utf8');
    let sig_data = fs.readFileSync(path + "index.html.asc", 'utf8');
    let pubkey_data = fs.readFileSync(path + "pubkey.asc", 'utf8');

    let msg = await openpgp.cleartext.fromText(msg_data);
    let sig = await openpgp.signature.readArmored(sig_data);
    let pubkey = await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey_data);

    openpgp.verify({
        message: msg,
        signature: sig,
        publicKeys: pubkey.keys
    }).then(function(verified) {
        console.log(verified);
    });
}

sandbox();
```

index.html:

```
Test!
```

index.html.sig:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=7Z6F
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

pubkey.asc:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=Hgou
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

`npm list` shows openpgp@4.10.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingo Klöcker answered this question [on the gnupg users mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2020-November/064391.html). To summarize, gpg's default mode of operation uses non-
text mode when signing something, and it appears OpenPGP.js defaults to text mode (at least in the way used here). Adding `--textmode` to the gpg command line allowed OpenPGP.js to verify the signature and thereby resolved the issue.

If text mode is not desired, one can also read binary data from the files instead:

```
...
    let msg_data = fs.readFileSync(path + "index.html", null);
    let sig_data = fs.readFileSync(path + "index.html.sig", null);
    let pubkey_data = fs.readFileSync(path + "pubkey.asc", 'utf8');

    let msg = await openpgp.message.fromBinary(msg_data);
    let sig = await openpgp.signature.read(sig_data);
    let pubkey = await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey_data);

    openpgp.verify({
        message: msg,
        signature: sig,
        publicKeys: pubkey.keys
    }).then(function(verified) {
        console.log(verified);
    });
...
```